# ¿Cómo llenar un arreglo con datos de un servicio en angular?

Tags: array, angular, typescript

Tengo esto en ejemplo.component.ts
Quiero reemplazar los arreglos de **columns** por datos de un servicio que funciona a la perfección

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    const chart2 = c3.generate({
      bindto: '#product-sales',
      data: {
        columns: [
          ['Iphone', 8, 6, 3, 7, 9, 10, 14, 12, 11, 9, 8, 7, 10, 6, 12, 10, 8],
          ['Ipad', 7, 2, 8, 3, 4, 5, 7, 6, 5, 6, 4, 3, 3, 12, 5, 6, 3]
        ],
        type: 'spline'
      }
})
}
```

El servicio solo cuenta con dos filas para este ejemplo: http://rubbercorp.net/servicio/serviciosales.php

```
export class SalesComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  listasales:Sale[];
  constructor(private salesService:SalesService) { }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.leerInfo();
  }

  leerInfo():void{
    this.salesService.leerinfo().subscribe(
      (res:Sale[]) =>{
          this.listasales = res;
      }
    )
  }
}
```

He intentado reemplazar los arreglos de **columns** por `Sale[0]` y `Sale[1]` respectivamente pero no obtengo resultado esperado

```
columns: [
          Sale[0],
          Sale[1]
        ]
```

Comment: El arreglo que estás intentando asignar es de Objetos, mientras que en el ejemplo que muestras el arreglo es de valores directos (primitivas).

Comment: Tal vez la conversión de Sale[0] y Sale[1] te funcione

Answer (score 0):

Creo que deberías pasar los datos adecuados a columns, mi propuesta quedaría así.

```js
const Sales = [{"nombreProd":"Iphone","v1":"3","v2":"4","v3":"6","v4":"5","v5":"7","v6":"6","v7":"9","v8":"13","v9":"11","v10":"9","v11":"10","v12":"13","v13":"8","v14":"10","v15":"14","v16":"12","v17":"13"},{"nombreProd":"Android","v1":"5","v2":"7","v3":"9","v4":"10","v5":"8","v6":"13","v7":"12","v8":"9","v9":"15","v10":"12","v11":"11","v12":"14","v13":"11","v14":"13","v15":"13","v16":"14","v17":"15"}];

let salesFormatted = [
  Object.values(Sales[0]).map(e => parseInt(e) ? parseInt(e) : e),
  Object.values(Sales[1]).map(e => parseInt(e) ? parseInt(e) : e),
];

console.log(salesFormatted);
```

Creo que esta es la forma en la que deberías pasar los datos

Comment: Si funciona de esa forma, pero la idea era pasar los datos del servicio y por lo que veo estas pasando datos locales

Comment: Ya encontré la forma que me funcionó, me he guiado de tu propuesta. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

He usado `listasales` cuyos datos se obtiene de `Sale[]` esto queda asi `listasales:Sale[];` el cual declare en `export class`

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  const Sales = this.listasales;
    const chart2 = c3.generate({
      bindto: '#product-sales',
      data: {
        columns: [
          Object.values(Sales[0]).map(e => parseInt(e) ? parseInt(e) : e),
          Object.values(Sales[1]).map(e => parseInt(e) ? parseInt(e) : e)
        ],
        type: 'spline'
      }
})
}
```